Solve the system $ - \frac{x^2}{2} + y^2 + z^2 = 2a^2 \quad \quad x^2 + - \frac{y^2}{2}+ z^2 = 2b^2 \quad \quad x^2 + y^2 - \frac{z^2}{2}= 2c^2$
I have to solve the system \begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      - \frac{x^2}{2} + y^2 + z^2 = 2a^2\\
      x^2 + - \frac{y^2}{2}+ z^2  = 2b^2\\
      x^2 + y^2 - \frac{z^2}{2}   = 2c^2
    \end{cases}\
\end{equation}
Where $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers. Then, proof that it is a neccesary and sufficient condition that $a,b,c$ are the sizes of the sides of a triangle for the existence of a solution $x,y,z$ being the sizes of the sides of a triangle.
Well, the first part about solving the system is the first thing I did and from Gaussian substitution I get $x^2=-\frac{4}{9} (a^2 - 2 (b^2 + c^2)), y^2= \frac{4}{9}(2 a^2 - b^2 + 2 c^2), z^2= \frac{4}{9} (2 a^2 + 2 b^2 - c^2)$. Now, the problem does not ask about real solutions but I think It is what I should go for because the second part of the problem.
So from the $x$ I get $a^2\leq2(b^2+c^2)$, from the $y$ I get $b^2\leq 2(a^2+c^2)$ and from the $z$ I get $c^2\leq 2(a^2+b^2)$. And here is where I do not know how to proceed.
EDIT (UNSOLVED, ERROR ON THE LAST INEQUALITY): After some comments here is what I think could be a solution: Say that $a,b,c$ are the sizes of the sides of a triangle, then, we got the inequalities $a<b+c$, $b < c+a$ and $c< b+a$ so $x^2=-\frac{4}{9} (a^2 - 2 (b^2 + c^2))>\frac{4}{9} (b-c)^2\geq 0$,  $y^2= \frac{4}{9}(2 a^2 - b^2 + 2 c^2)>\frac{4}{9}(a-c)^2\geq0$ and $z^2= \frac{4}{9} (2 a^2 + 2 b^2 - c^2)>\frac{4}{9}(a-b)^2\geq0$. So we can be sure that there are going to be real solution to the system, however to ensure that $x,y,z$ are the sizes of the sides of a triangle we are going to proof that there exist $u,v,w$ positive real numbers such that $x=u+v,y=v+w, z=w+u$ (Ravi substitution). Then $(u+v)^2=-\frac{4}{9} (a^2 - 2 (b^2 + c^2)), (v+w)^2= \frac{4}{9}(2 a^2 - b^2 + 2 c^2), (u+w)^2= \frac{4}{9} (2 a^2 + 2 b^2 - c^2)$, so $v= \frac{4}{3}(\sqrt{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}+\sqrt{2a^2+2c^2-b^2}-\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2})>|a-b|+|b-c|-|a-c|= 0$(ERROR). Doing the same with the rest give us the condition. To get the other direction we can reformulate the system to be $$\begin{cases}\frac{16}9\left(-\frac12a^2+b^2+c^2\right)=2x^2\\\frac{16}9\left(a^2-\frac12b^2+c^2\right)=2y^2\\\frac{16}9\left(a^2+b^2-\frac12c^2\right)=2z^2\end{cases}$$ That is the same system scaled by a constant.

Please always use dollars for formulas in the title.

Hint: $a,b,c$ sides of a triangle $\iff \sqrt 2(a,b,c)$ sides of a triangle $\iff \sqrt 2(a,b,c)$ medians of a triangle.

For some help, note Apollonius's theorem and see this post.

You've already got
$$x^2=\frac 49(-a^2+2b^2+2c^2)\tag1$$
$$y^2=\frac 49(2a^2-b^2+2c^2)\tag2$$
$$z^2=\frac 49(2a^2+2b^2-c^2)\tag3$$
and proved that if $a\lt b+c,b\lt c+a$ and $c\lt a+b$, then $x^2,y^2,z^2$ are positive.
Here, Sahaj's comment is helpful.
Let $A:=\frac 43a,B:=\frac 43b$ and $C:=\frac 43c$.
Then, $(1)(2)(3)$ can be written as
$$B^2+C^2=2\bigg(\bigg(\frac A2\bigg)^2+x^2\bigg)$$
$$C^2+A^2=2\bigg(\bigg(\frac B2\bigg)^2+y^2\bigg)$$
$$A^2+B^2=2\bigg(\bigg(\frac C2\bigg)^2+z^2\bigg)$$
We can say by Apollonius's theorem that $x,y,z$ are the lengths of the medians of a triangle whose side lengths are $A,B,C$.
It is known that medians of a triangle can make a triangle.

If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are sides of a triangle then $a<b+c$, so $$x^2=\frac49\left(-a^2+2b^2+2c^2\right)>\frac49\left(b^2-2bc+c^2\right)>0$$so $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Likewise, by symmetry, $y,z\in\mathbb{R}$, so if $a$, $b$ and $c$ are sides of a triangle then $x$, $y$ and $z$ exist, so $x$, $y$ and $z$ can only be the sides of a triangle if $a$, $b$ and $c$ are sides of a triangle.
Now note that $$\begin{cases}\frac{16}9\left(-\frac12a^2+b^2+c^2\right)=2x^2\\\frac{16}9\left(a^2-\frac12b^2+c^2\right)=2y^2\\\frac{16}9\left(a^2+b^2-\frac12c^2\right)=2z^2\end{cases}$$This is a scaled version of the system in the question but with $a$, $b$ and $c$ interchanged with $x$, $y$ and $z$ respectively. This means that $x$, $y$ and $z$ are sides of a triangle only if a solution for $a$, $b$ and $c$ exists, so $a$, $b$ and $c$ are sides of a triangle if $x$, $y$ and $z$ are sides of s triangle.
Therefore, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are sides of a triangle if and only if $x$, $y$ and $z$ are sides of s triangle.

$b^2-2bc+c^2=(b-c)^2<0$?

Brain fade from me. Hopefully my answer is fine now?

@Sai_Mehta not quite. So you have shown that if $a, b, c$ form an triangle, then $x, y, z$ exist, but you didn't show $x, y,z$ form a triangle. If you did so, then the other direction can be deduced by the same token as the $(x, y, z)\mapsto (a,b,c)$ is just a scaled version of $(a,b,c)\mapsto (x,y,z)$ (Good observation for scaling BTW).

@Just_a_user I think I can fix that problem, by Ravis substitution we know that we can form a triangle if there exist $u,v,w$ positive real number such that $x=u+v, y=u+w, z=w+v$. Putting those summs on the equations for $x^2,y^2,z^2$ and knowing that $a,b,c$ form a triangle give us the $u,v,w$ in terms of $a,b,c$. This being solved, and by the scaled version given by Sai_Metha we got the iff.

@MiguelCG That could work, but I haven't seen how can you get $u, v, w$ in terms of $a, b, c$ yet (and prove they are positive).

@Justauser I have edited the post with the solution, Is it right? Thanks!

@MiguelCG It doesn't seem right yet. I'm not sure how you can show $\sqrt{2(b^2+c^2)-a^2}>|a-b|$ (but it can be shown $\sqrt{2(b^2+c^2)-a^2}>|b-c|$), even if you do, then the last term $-\sqrt{\text{blah}}<-|a-c|$, so you cannot get the inequality. Also the Ravi substitution doesn't really do much, because you essentially just take the square roots and try to show $x+y-z>0$. I have some clues about a geometric solution, but haven't figured it out yet.

@Justauser True, totally missed the last term.
